# What is the best way to measure the memory usage of a C# function?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for an accurate way to measure memory usage of a C# program under Windows operating system. I'm using Visual Studio for programming my code and I want to know its time consuming for performance. Really, I tried to use the Task Manager, but I do not get an accurate measurment.

Please, if any one know an accurate way to measure the memory consumption, please help me and thanks alot

Comment: Are you using VS 2010? If so what Edition?

Comment: You can use VTune for memory checks and optimization issues....

Comment: Yes, I use Visual Studio 2010 ... do you advance me to use VTune

Answer (score 1):

In order to measure memory usage, you'll need to use a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). You can head over to this SO question: "[What are some good .NET profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)" to receive all the information you could want on profiling tools. Head to their respective websites to learn how to use them.